# Change exit code on a single line using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am using the savscan command but this returns 3 instead of 1 when a malware is detected, and I need to get 1 if a malware is detected, I tried the following:

```
$ bash -c "savscan -f -archive infectedfile.exe && if [ $? -eq 3 ]; then exit 1 ; fi"
$ echo $?
$ 0 
$ bash -c "savscan -f -archive infectedfile.exe ; if [ $? -eq 3 ]; then exit 1 ; fi"
$ echo $?
$ 0
```

but I still get the exit code 0, I also need to run everything in one line

Comment: `&&` only runs things on the right-hand side if the exit status of the thing on the left is 0 (the truthy/success value).

Comment: So how will it be the right way to do it?

Comment: Use `;` (or a newline) as your separator if you want to run the thing on the right regardless, or `||` if you want to run it only when the thing on the left has a false-y exit status.

Comment: BTW, note that Stack Overflow's rules specify that our scope is limited to "practical, answerable" questions. Insisting on a one-liner (without regard to whether readability, portability, robustness, &c. is being traded against towards that end) without an explanation of why one has a *practical* need for same is a good way to invite a skeptical eye wrt. whether a question fits that guideline.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest questioning whether the specification underlying the question is a wise one. "X could not be tested" and "X is definitively malware" are very different states, and it's wise to be able to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a function wrapper for this:

```
savscan() {
  local retval
  command savscan "$@"; retval=$?
  (( retval == 3 )) && retval=1
  return "$retval"
}

savscan -f -archive infectedfile.exe
```

...as adding more rules about how to mutate your exit status is as simple as adding additional commands inspecting and modifying `retval`, as you see fit.

If you for some reason insist on defining and invoking this function in a single line, this could look like:

```
savscan() { local retval; command savscan "$@"; retval=$?; (( retval == 3 )) && retval=1; return "$retval"; }; savscan -f -archive infectedfile.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not test the return status of bash command and adjust as needed.

```
bash -c "savscan -f -archive infectedfile.exe" || [ $? -ne 3 ]
```

My tests:

```
$ bash -c "savscan -f -archive infectedfile.exe" || [ $? -ne 3 ]
$ echo $?
1
$ bash -c "savscan -f -archive okfile.exe" || [ $? -ne 3 ]
$ echo $?
0
```